# libtorrent ssl need cert (maybe) (Windows)

Tags: ssl, openssl, bittorrent, libtorrent, monotorrent

I am working on a project using libtorrent for some clients and a open tracker using mono torrent.

Pc1: Runs a tracker using mono torrent, which hosts the .torrent
Pc2: Runs a lib torrent client and hosts the content referenced in the torrent and has the .torrent, which is added to the client by passing a signed certificate, a matching private key, and dhparams and the password for the signed certificate.
Pc3: the same as Pc2 but does not host any content referenced by the torrent

The torrent is created with a CA certificate and a private key matching the CA which the signed certificates is signed against, using openssl. With no errors. (This is done on a seperate Pc from the other 3).

When I run the tracker I get no errors, only that it's running and tracking the torrent.

When I run the clients it gives me a torrent need cert alert, and I then set_ssl_certificate on the handle for the torrent, and then resumes, and I get a torrent_error_alert telling me that the torrent doesn't exist, and finaly it changes state to checking and then seeding/downloading depending on which client it is (the uploader or downloader).

The problem is then, that there is no traffic between the clients.

I can see that they are connected to the tracker, and are listening on both normal ports and the ssl ports, but there is never a connection between the two clients (Using TcpView).

There is no difference when I run with or without admin rights.

Anyone who has experienced this, or might have a solution/pointer in the right direction?

Many thanks in advance.